# transloco-preload-langs failes with "No provider for TranslocoPreloadLangsService" in angular application

Tags: angular, internationalization, transloco

In my application I'm using `@ngneat/transloco`. Recently I updated angular from v12 to v16 and there were no problems with transloco. Now I need language preload feature therefore `@ngneat/transloco-preload-langs` was installed. I followed official [documentation](https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/docs/plugins/preload-langs) and added `provideTranslocoPreloadLangs()` to `transloco-root.module`.

However in runtime I see this error:
[image]

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.6",
    "@ngneat/transloco": "6.0.0",
    "@ngneat/transloco-preload-langs": "5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
```

transloco-root.module

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class TranslocoHttpLoader implements TranslocoLoader {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getTranslation(lang: string) {
    return this.http.get<Translation>(`/assets/i18n/${lang}.json`);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  exports: [TranslocoModule],
  providers: [
    provideTranslocoPreloadLangs(["en"]),
    provideTransloco({
      config: {
        availableLangs: ["en", "tr"],
        defaultLang: "en",
        prodMode: environment.production
      },
      loader: TranslocoHttpLoader
    })
  ]
})
export class TranslocoRootModule {}
```

app.module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SharedModule,
    LayoutModule,
    ...
    TranslocoRootModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initApp,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**NOTE**: I did not convert components to standalone version yet. This should not affect I believe but I'm not sure.

Also there is no issue related to this on github https://github.com/ngneat/transloco/issues

Did someone face this problem?

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Comment: Still not. If you have solution you can post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like the issue has been resolve in @ngneat/transloco-preload-langs@5.0.1

here is the [bug report](https://github.com/ngneat/transloco/issues/726)